# throwing custom exception in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, try-catch, throw, nsexception

I have following code . . .

```
@try
{
    NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",nil];

   // the below code will raise an exception

   [array objectAtIndex:11];
}
@catch(NSException *exception)
{
    // now i want to create a custom exception and throw it .

    NSException * myexception = [[NSException alloc] initWithName:exception.name
                                                           reason:exception.reason
                                                         userInfo:exception.userInfo];


   //now i am saving callStacksymbols to a mutable array and adding some objects

    NSMUtableArray * mutableArray = [[NSMUtableArray alloc] 
                                       initWithArray:exception.callStackSymbols];

    [mutableArray addObject:@"object"];

    //but my problem is when i try to assign this mutable array to myexception i am getting following error

    myexception.callStackSymbols = (NSArray *)mutableArray;

    //error : no setter method 'setCallStackSymbols' for assignment to property

    @throw myexception;

}
```

please help to fix this , i wanted to add some extra objects to callStackSymbols . . . .Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not try and recover from exceptions.  Exceptions in iOS and OS X should be treated as unrecoverable, fatal,  programmer error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are coming from a Java background, exception handling in Objective-C feels strange at first. In fact you normally don't use `NSException` for your own error handling. Use `NSError` instead, as you can find it at many other points through the SDK, when handling unexpected error situations (e.g. URL operations).

Error handling is done (roughly) like this:

Write a method that takes a pointer to NSError as parameter...

```
- (void)doSomethingThatMayCauseAnError:(NSError*__autoreleasing *)anError
{
    // ...
    // Failure situation
    NSDictionary tUserInfo = @{@"myCustomObject":@"customErrorInfo"};
    NSError* tError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"MyDomain" code:123 userInfo:tUserInfo];
    anError = tError;
}
```

The userInfo dictionary is the place to put whatever information needs to be provided with the error.

When calling the method, you check for an error situation like this...

```
// ...
NSError* tError = nil;
[self doSomethingThatMayCauseAnError:&tError];
if (tError) {
    // Error occurred!
    NSString* tCustomErrorObject = [tError.userInfo valueForKey:@"myCustomObject"];
    // ...
}
```

If you are calling an SDK method that could result in an "`NSError != nil`", you can add your own information to the userInfo dictionary and pass this error to the caller as shown above.

Comment: NSError is not exception throwing. I feel that isn't stated clear enough in the java